# How can I find the optimization of a function with more than one variable over a specific interval?

Tags: r

```
func_2 <- function(p,N){
  f <- sqrt ((p* (1- p) )/N)
  return(f)
}

maxmim <- optimize(func_2, c(0,1), maximum = TRUE)
```

The error message keeps popping up saying argument "N" missing, what do I do to find my optimization value for p?

Comment: `optim` is the general purpose optimization tool in base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice one can use `optim` to find the maximum for a two variable function. However, it requires vector input:

```
func_3 <- function(vec){
  func_2(vec[1],vec[2])
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
optim(par = c(p = 0.1, N = 0.1), fn =  func_3, 
      lower = c(p = 0, N = 0), upper = c(p = 1, N = 1),
      method="L-BFGS-B", control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

However, your function maximizes over the interval of 0 to 1 at p = 0.5 and N = limit as N approaches 0. This evaluates to `NaN` and thus can't be found by `optim` using a method that is compatible with lower and upper limits.